# mysql autocasting string to integer

Tags: php, mysql, casting, doctrine-orm, implicit-conversion

my question is a general question:

doctrine treats

`$entitity->getTest()->clear();`

into this sql query:

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE test_id = '6'
```

-> test_id is an integer in the database, mysql converts automatic the value so it works.
but the right query would be :

```
    DELETE FROM test WHERE test_id = 6
```

I found some Diskussions here:

stackoverflow.com/questions/21762075/mysql-automatically-cast-convert-a-string-to-a-number

code.openark.org/blog/mysql/implicit-casting-you-dont-want-to-see-around

mysql doc says:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html

> "The following rules describe how conversion occurs for comparison operations" (..) In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

The Documentation also tells an issue with it:

> Comparisons that use floating-point numbers (or values that are converted to floating-point numbers) are approximate because such numbers are inexact. This might lead to results that appear inconsistent

So why doctrine orm and also dbal acts so? Is this not a problem with tables with integers? only with bigint?

Also look here:

http://www.cubrid.org/cubrid_implicit_type_conversion

-> There it tells that this is not a Problem.

So my question is: Do a query with where int_val = '1' (string) is no big deal or can this be dangerous. if this is dangerous, haste doctrine a design issue here?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> - If one or both arguments are `NULL`, the result of the comparison is `NULL`, except for the `NULL`-safe `<=>` equality comparison operator. For
>     `NULL <=> NULL`, the result is true. No conversion is needed.
> - If both arguments in a comparison operation are strings, they are compared as strings.
> - If both arguments are integers, they are compared as integers.
> - Hexadecimal values are treated as binary strings if not compared to a number.
> - If one of the arguments is a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` column and the other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>     before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more
>     ODBC-friendly. Note that this is not done for the arguments to `IN()`!
>     To be safe, always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when
>     doing comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using
>     `BETWEEN` with date or time values, use `CAST()` to explicitly convert the
>     values to the desired data type.
> - If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if
>     the other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point
>     values if the other argument is a floating-point value.
> - In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point (real) numbers.

Your case falls under "all other cases".

The string will be cast to a `FLOAT` and then compared against your `int_val`.

If string casts nicely (values like `'1'`, `'0.1'` or `'1E5'`), the resulting value will be compared to the integer.

If not (say you pass a value like `'1235xxx'`), the possible leading digits will be cast to a float (`0` if none), and the rest is truncated. In addition, a warning will be generated.

The reason for passing the id in a string might be that your id does not necessarily have to be an integer. It could be a string or a date as well.

Probably the ORM has a generic code for generating `DELETE` query which would work on any datatype.

Answer (score 0):

> When an operator is used with operands of different types, type conversion occurs to make the operands compatible. Some conversions occur implicitly. For example, MySQL automatically converts numbers to strings as necessary, and vice versa. [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/type-conversion.html)

This also applies when selecting/inserting/updating, using the column type as reference.

So, if you do `SELECT * FROM users WHERE balance = '1234'` and the type of the column `balance` is `DECIMAL (6,2)` the following is implied.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT ('1234', DECIMAL (6,2));
+---------------------------------+
| CONVERT ('1234', DECIMAL (6,2)) |
+---------------------------------+
|                         1234.00 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You'll always have a default value for those values who can't be converted.

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT ('test', DECIMAL (6,2));
+---------------------------------+
| CONVERT ('test', DECIMAL (6,2)) |
+---------------------------------+
|                            0.00 |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

So no, there's no vulnerability involved (at least at MySQL side).